# Wouldn't be caught dead

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

> — What do you think of that hat?
> — I wouldn't be caught *dead* in it!

... ce qui veut dire : Même mort, même quand il ne me resterait aucune volonté, je le refuserais toujours ! Ce serait trop embarrassant !

Y a-t-il un bon équivalent en français qui partage le ton humoristique et follement exagéré ? Ceux proposés dans [le corpus de Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/wouldn%27t+be+caught+dead.html) sont très anodins.

Answer (score 3):

On a (presque) la même chose en français, un équivalent parfait : *Plutôt mourir* (*que* + verbe à l'inf.)...

> *I wouldn't be seen dead with him* (informal) / plutôt mourir que de me montrer en sa compagnie. ([*Larousse en ligne*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/dead/574171) anglais-français)

« Dans des formules exprimant avec force un serment ou une affirmation et indiquant que la volonté de mourir est dans une alternative, la seule option à une autre action que l'on repousse » (TLFi, [*mourir*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mourir)) ; même possiblement avec l'auto-damnation pour ainsi dire :

> *Que je meure si* on me voit porter ça !

Il y a certainement exagération et la déclamation solennelle permettra certainement la dose d'humour requise.

Comment: Le premier est trop fort pour un chapeau et le second est trop vieux (on ne dit plus ça (1884)).

Comment: En français, on dit « plutôt mourir » pour des choses plus importantes, plus sérieuses, pour des convictions politiques, des croyances religieuse ou personnelles ; ce sont les gens qui n'ont pas trop le sens de la culture française qui diraient cela pour un chapeau.

Comment: Je ne dicte rien du tout, c'est l'impression très nette que je tire de mes lectures, des œuvres cinématographiques, … de la vie !

Comment: Sans le rejoindre dans l'attaque ad hominem, je suis plutôt d'accord avec @mastödantirâfamî sur le coup. On peut utiliser « plutôt mourir » dans des contextes tout à fait futiles, sans enjeu, humoristiques : « plutôt mourir que de toucher à un plat infect de cette cantine ! »

Comment: @guillaume31 Je suis d'accord aussi sur ce question de plat infecte, mais je ne conçois pas ce contexte comme futile ; il est très important de veiller à ne pas se donner la nausée.

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî Dans ce cas encore il s'agit d'exagération. // « De toutes façons …, qui t'échappe. » : pas clair. // On doit inférer la portée des termes illustrés à partir des exemples donnés, ils sont donnés dans ce but, mais on ne doit pas considérer que l'on peut en déduire toute la portée, c'est vrai, _ je ne  fais pas cette erreur_, et je considère presque toujours qu'il n'y a pas assez d'exemples. // Un maitre est énormément plus important qu'un chapeau, sacrifiez sans hésitation votre chapeau favori pour un maitre utile. (1/3)

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî Respecter les normes considérées : « pas ragoutant » est énormément différent de « infecte » ;  « pas ragoutant »,  c'est encore  mangeable, « infecte », ça écœure. // Je ne suis pas d'accord, au contraire ce serait la solution qui se rapproche le plus de « caught dead   », le seul qui puisse prétendre à rendre l'humour que l'on trouve dans l'anglais ; c'est évident : la distanciation par le biais de la mort n'est pas suffisante et la distanciation par le biais d'une représentation ne l'est pas non plus (humour) ; évidemment la mort est plus forte.  (2/3)

Answer (score 2):

Toujours avec le thème de la (vie et de la) mort, j'ai vu qu'au Québec on semble calquer un peu une  phrase similaire à celle en question, par exemple en traduisant [probablement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XR1CmPj2PkU) les propos d'un joueur de baseball à partir de l'espagnol :

> **Même mort**, je ne voudrais pas signer avec les Yankees. (Vladimir
> Guerrero fils, propos sur *El Dotol Nastra* rapportés par le [*Journal
> de Montréal*](https://www.journaldemontreal.com/2022/11/05/vladimir-guerrero-fils--meme-mort-je-ne-voudrais-pas-signer-avec-les-yankees))

Answer (score 1):

« *Pour rien au monde* » est une possibilité qui convient mais à laquelle manque totalement le côté humoristique ; l'exagération  fait son effet mais sans amuser.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/monde))  **Pour rien au monde**. En aucun cas.
> • Il ne devait, pour rien au monde, tomber dans les niaiseries sentimentales: on se répète de mauvaises phrases de romans (Larbaud, F. Marquez, 1911, p.69).

« Pour tout l'or du monde » est plus spécifique, mais le côté humoristique fait  plutôt défaut en considération de ce que  l'idée dans l'expression anglaise communique au sujet de l'état d'esprit du locuteur, même si on sait qu'une quantité d'or en comparaison insignifiante ne peut pas manquer de prouver l'assertion fausse.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/or)) **Pour tout l'or du monde** (dans une phrase négative). Pour rien au monde.
> • Pour tout l'or du monde, je ne voudrais pas changer de maître (Musset,A. del Sarto, 1834, ii, 1, p.76).

Dans le même ton mais dans un registre qui commence à être familier on trouve la tournure suivante.

> **on me paierait que je ne** …

([réf. Le français correct: Guide pratique des difficultés -
Maurice Grevisse, ‎Michèle Lenoble-Pinson](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_fran%C3%A7ais_correct/Cva6FlQ-5nYC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22me+paierait+que%22&pg=PA440&printsec=frontcover)) On me paierait QUE je ne le ferais pas ( Petit Robert )

In fact Robert's bilingual dictionary gives a translation for this very context that is the first one proposed above..

> (Robert) **I wouldn't be seen dead wearing that hat** or **wearing that hat (familier)**    *je ne porterais ce chapeau pour rien au monde !*

Apparemment, il n'y aurait pas de très bon équivalent en français.

Il existe une possibilité de traduction par un chemin détourné, mais qui montre un certain humour.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/peinture)) Fam. **Ne (pas/plus) pouvoir voir qqn en peinture**. Ne (pas/plus) pouvoir le supporter; le détester.
> • Elle ne peut pas le voir en peinture. Elle a tort, c'est un garçon très riche (Dumas fils, Dame Camélias,1848, p.78).
> • Il me prenait en grippe. Il pouvait plus me voir en peinture (Céline, Mort à crédit,1936, p.166).

- Je ne pourrais pas me voir en peinture avec un chapeau pareil. (*C'est à dire, je me prendrais en horreur avec un chapeau pareil.*)

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî Oui, premièrement le côté humoristique est faible en comparaison avec l'humour dans l'expression anglaise , et deuxièmement ce n'est pas mourir mais être vu mort, un monde de différence ; encore une erreur grossière, navrant.

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî Je ne parle pas de défaut, je ne le mentionne pas pas mais c'est évident il s'agit de qualité et qui ne dira pas que la _qualité_ de l'idée anglaise, du point de vue humour, a quelque chose d'inégalable ? C'est TOUOUT !

Comment: @m Chez Larousse ils parlent d'une personne : des haines bien plus grandes que celles pour un chapeau ; lisez l'exemple.

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî  Faux, Faux, Faux. Copier c'est être l'égal selon vous ? Il y a des choses que vous ne pouvez que copier.

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî  Ma vision de la langue en embuscade ! On aura tout entendu !

Comment: I like "on me paierait que je ne le ferais pas" as an equivalent of the similar and idiomatic English expression "You couldn't *pay* me to do it!"

Comment: @LukeSawczak >It is not much different from the others as far as the basic idea, which is remuneration, and  in the way of  presenting a humourous quirk, it is not better; I have the impression I never saw anyone smile at this sort of remark

Comment: La tournure réflexive _je ne peux pas me voir en peinture_ évoque presque exclusivement le manque de confiance ou d'estime de soi. Dans d'autres cas, même avec l'aspect réflexif, elle est employée pour un objet qui n'est pas relié à la personne, de manière relâchée, par exemple _c'est un chapeau que je ne peux pas me voir en peinture_. L'emploi que tu en fait sonne faux.

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî  « C'est un chapeau que je ne peux pas me voir en peinture » est biscornu, pas correct. L'emploi que j'en fait c'est « me voir en peinture _avec ce chapeau_ » (on se voit en peinture comme on veut).

Answer (score 1):

**Jamais de la vie !**

Pour continuer le sens littéral ou la traduction "Valette" *no way*, il y a en plus une comparaison avec la phrase en anglais : la vie et la mort.

[Wiktionnaire](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/jamais_de_la_vie) donne les traductions suivantes :

> (informal) not on your life! not in this lifetime! not a chance! no
> way Jose! not in a million years! absolutely not!

J'hésite un peu de le dire mais il y aussi quelques extrêmes en ordre croissant (avertissement) :

- Mais j'hallucine.
- Attends . . .  je vais rendre.
- Ça sans me faire découper les veines ?